# Find Couchbase Owner of Expensive Query (CPU)

Tags: couchbase

We are having trouble with CPU spikes on our Couchbase cluster.  Does anyone know of any good techniques to track down who/what is causing this?

The best I've got so far is polling admin/vitals and if CPU exceeds some threshold then dump out admin/active_requests.  That will give us some indication of what is causing this.

Is there any way to find which user is associated with an expensive query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now (Couchbase 4.6.0), the completed_requests/active_requests log doesn't show where the query originated, so there's no way to get that information normally. A silly, but feasible way to track that would be to add a dummy parameter to each query that would hold some identifying information, like application or user id.

E.g. `SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE field="value" AND "myapp"="myapp"`
or a parameterized query where the dummy parameter name identifies the source, and evaluates to `true` like so: 
`SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE field="value" AND $myapp` and pass `true` into `$myapp`

Now you can find all the queries from a certain source in completed_requests, or figure out the source of an active query.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts David.